# Cross-platform Extract of Large Volume of data from databases to file

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, db2, extract

I have a requirement to extract large amount of data (say between 1 and 100 million rows overall) from a database into multiple flat files. Data could be coming from multiple tables and we have to limit the columns selected to avoid extracting sensitive information.

Our source database can be Oracle, MS SQL Server or DB2. The table names would be the same under any source database. I'm looking for a solution that works across all types.

Another requirement is to have minimal footprint, so we can't install large ETL tools.

I'm considering creating a java program that would connect via JDBC to read the data from the DB and write to file. What should be my considerations? One I think would be performance. I'm thinking of batching the file writes to reduce I/O operations. Is there a utility that works across these databases for selectively extracting data? Any suggestions and other concerns I need to consider?

Comment: I don't see a specific problem here. You query the DB and stream the rows to a file with an appropriate buffer size (like you said). That's ok. Stack Overflow isn't so good for questions of the form "here's a working solution, what can I improve?".

Comment: I see. I'm looking for validation as I feel I'm missing something or may have overlooked a better solution. Thanks for confirming though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is the right tool in my opinion. You didn't tell us which hardware platform you want to run this on, but it's no big hassle to get it installed on windows, linux, mac os, solaris, aix .. whatever you need. If you bundle the pure-java database drivers with your jar, you can get the program to work almost everywhere without even needing to install some database clients (ok, i'm not sure if mysql has a pure java driver, but oracle and db2 do). Java might be a bit more expensive in terms of CPU use than other implementations, especially if you use a pure java client, but the limiting factor will be disk/network IO anyway, not the CPU.

I've done similar stuff in Perl and C before, and installing my software on a new system was always a kind of PITA, since you need to install client software first, and in the case of perl, you almost certainly need a compiler as well to get DBD::Oracle and DBD::DB2 compiled. With my generic jar, it's just a "copy one jar file that contains the type 4 drivers to the target, make sure java is installed, and it's done" now.

Comment: The hardware platform can be x86-64, Itanium or SPARC. My requirements specifically is to perform the extraction on PeopleSoft databases. Here, java is pre-installed on their servers.